# Properties aren't resolved in Spring context XML

Tags: java, spring, properties, javabeans

I'm creating my Spring context inside a `static main` method with

```
return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Inside `applicationContext.xml` I'm wiring one of my beans with

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${db.driverclassname}</value>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>
```

I've got a `.properties` file on my class path that contains the value `db.driverclassname`.

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
        Could not load JDBC driver class [${db.driverclassname}]
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Spring 2.5.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't you need a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.7/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) ?

e.g.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"      
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
      <value>classpath:project.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

[This article](http://almaer.com/blog/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-a-nice-clean-way-to-share) details usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:your.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```